# "E: Unable to locate package ruby and E: Package 'texinfo' has no installation candidate" occurs when installing Ruby and GCC

Tags: ruby, linux, npm, gcc, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install node.js and npm and before installing them it was required to install Ruby and GCC so while installing Ruby and GCC with the following cmmand:
`sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev` in Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, xenial.
I get the error:

[image]

But with the command:
`ruby -v`
I get the result:
`ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]`
I have tried updating the cache, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> with the command: ruby -v I get the result:

This means that ruby is already installed, no need to install it again.

> sudo apt-get install … texinfo

Why do you want to install texinfo at all? It's not required by nodejs and npm.

Also, why on Earth are you installing stuff in an unsupported 5-years-old operating system? Even LTS versions of Ubuntu should be upgraded to the next LTS version, or you will incur in incompatibilities sooner or later. Ubuntu 16.04 has not been maintained since more than 1 year ago.